# Creating a dynamic Rest client

Tags: java, rest

I need to develop a client interface to rest webservices in Java.
The idea is to provide a form-gui that permits to choose the url, method, Headers, cookie and body (for post request)
and then clicking on the submit a generic rest Proxy client method is called, this set up the informations and invokes Jersey / JAX-RS client methods (via a series of if / then condition).

In order to not to reinvent the wheel, is there something already built to allow that?
Thank you!

Comment: it has to be done in java, not other tools like soapUI. It will be part of a big java application.

Answer (score 0):

We usually use Chrome REST console in order to do that:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn

It's pretty useful but still have some limits, for instance when you need to change the UserAgent.
In those specific case I recommend the old commands `curl` or `wget`.

EDIT: this client proved to be even more useful: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

It allow you to save your favourite HTTP request to your service.

Comment: Thank you, I need to use it in a java application

Comment: Then, you should state this requirement in your question!

Comment: Here is a question, why should it be embedded *in* a java application? what kind of java application? Desktop (Swing or SWT?)? Web?

Comment: hi @thermz thank you for your interest. It has to be done in java, in a big application that present a gui (it doesn't matter the technical detail, consider it is swing for instance)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rest Client in Firefox or Advanced Rest Client in chrome. They are actually  plugins for each browser.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to embed it in a java application